# Transaction history is empty on NFT mint account

Tags: account, transaction, history

I have this NFT's mint address on devnet where no transaction history can be found: E4xbqXvy1tHjfBwJpR5WT4h3xMXgmb5UX7wkoChUPB4g
I'm confused how this is happened, because I also have the transaction has that created the NFT, but the explorer shows no result for it. Any clues?

Comment: Can confirm I'm seeing no transaction history for that account on both explorer.solana.com and solana.fm. Not sure if that is intended behavior, certainly doesn't seem like it. Do you have the transaction signature from when you created it?

Answer (score 2):

Transaction history is not stored longterm for devnet or testnet, so it's normal that you can't fetch old transactions on devnet.

Mainnet-beta is the only network with longterm transaction storage.

> *Devnet may be subject to ledger resets.*
>
> Source: https://docs.solana.com/clusters#devnet